# PowerBI - Conditional formatting of specific cells

Tags: excel, powerbi, conditional-formatting

This is what I have created on Excel:
[image: Excel]

I am trying to publish it on Power BI. I am struggling to find a setting to color specific cells according to what I have created in Excel.
[image: PowerBI]

The conditional formatting guide (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-conditional-table-formatting/) suggests coloring the cells based on the value, but I want the colors to be static regardless of the values.

Question: How can I choose to color the cells according to my specific requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I choose to color the cells according to my
>   specific requirement?

There is an option to develop a [custom visual](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals) with this behaviour.

There's a [table visual template](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-tools/tree/master/templates/visuals/table) you can use as a start.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Foxan and user5226582. I am not sure if this answer is appropriate to SO's requirement for an answer, but in the end I did a hacky way of taking a screenshot of the colour without the values from Excel and inserted it as a background image to the table on PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

For each cell you need to do the following:

1. extract

   - column name, and
   - value in 1st column (***HI/CoF ($)***) of current row,
2. take the last symbol from both,
3. convert it to number and
4. check resulting values in conditional formatting to determine color.

As an option, you may add both numbers and assign color according to the sum: 2 is green, 14 is red, other colors between. However, it probably wouldn't result in exactly same color matrix as is in your example.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called [Column Formatting](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-november-feature-summary/#columnFormatting) in Power BI. You can find it in the format pane in Table or Matrix visualizations.

[image: column formatting]

However, the best you can do is formatting per column level (and header / total), for font color and background color. Per cell level is not available in Power BI yet. You may consider submit a [feature request](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas) to Power BI if you want to.